# How to plot a directed Graph in R with networkD3?

Tags: r, d3.js, directed-graph, htmlwidgets, networkd3

when I am ploting a directed graph with NetworkD3 , The edges are not directed , how can I fix it ? 
an Example :

```
library(networkD3)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
         Source = "source", Target = "target",
         Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
         Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```

I want the result to be directed This is the definetion of directed Graph:

"A directed graph is graph, i.e., a set of objects (called vertices or nodes) that are connected together, where all the edges are directed from one vertex to another. A directed graph is sometimes called a digraph or a directed network."

I want the edges be like arrows , how can i do it in networkD3 , I hope it's clear.

Thx.

Comment: By directed Graph , I mean a graph whose edges are like arrow . :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `forceNetwork()` function of the networkD3 package does not draw arrows on the links for directed graphs. I can say that quite definitively because I am one of the currently active developers working on the package and I know the function and its options very well. You can also run `?networkD3::forceNetwork` in your R console to see the help file and all of the possible options for the `forceNetwork()` function.

**UPDATE (2017.03.20)**

This feature (plotting arrows for a directed graph) is now part of the official CRAN release version of `networkD3`. Once installed, you can plot a directed forceNetwork with arrows with...

```
library(networkD3)
URL <- paste0("https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
              "master/JSONdata/miserables.json")
MisJson <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)
ValjeanInds <- which(MisJson$links == 11, arr = TRUE)[, 1]
ValjeanCols <- ifelse(1:nrow(MisJson$links) %in% ValjeanInds, "#bf3eff", "#666")

forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source", Target = "target", 
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name", Group = "group", opacity = 0.8, 
             linkColour = ValjeanCols, arrows = TRUE, zoom = TRUE)
```

and it should look like...
[image: directed forceNetwork with arrows]

Comment: Many Thanks , do you know any other package in R for drawing interactive directed graphs ?

Comment: igraph is the most comprehensive network analysis and visualization package that I know of http://igraph.org

Comment: Yeah , Thanks , I used it before , but the results(graphs) are not interactive.

Comment: Just found the visNetwork package. That might work for you.

Comment: I'm working on a new branch of networkD3 that will add arrows to the link lines. You can test it out by installing from github with... `devtools::install_github('cjyetman/networkD3', ref = 'directed_arrows')`. Then add `arrow = TRUE` to the `forceNetwork()` call and it should use arrows. I'd be interested in your feedback.

Comment: @Amir.S please see the update to my answer. We'd be happy to get your feedback on the implementation of this feature which you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much , looks very great.
I'll be back soon with testing it. thanks alot , sorry for my late answer.

Comment: @CJYetman Is it possible to place labels near to each edge (a directed weighted graph like in igraph)?

Comment: @peer sorry, not sure what you mean. may you should open a new question with greater detail?